# Add exact number of spaces to start of string using java.util.Formatter

Tags: java, text-formatting

I am using Formatter to output Java code to a file. I want to add a specific number of spaces to the start of each line. My problem is I cannot find a way to do this "neatly". The standard options seem to only allow adding a minimum number of spaces but not a specific number of spaces.

As a work around, I am currently doing the following:
`out.format("%7s%s", "", "My text");` but I'd like to do it with only two arguments like this `out.format("%7s", "My text");`.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this using the standard Formatter options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you want here:

```
out.format("xxx%10sxxx", "My text");
// prints: xxx   My textxxx
```

While:

```
out.format("xxx%-10sxxx", "My text");
// prints: xxxMy text   xxx
```

As far as I know, there is no way to do the old C-style formatting to specify the size in an argument like "%*s" because then you could pass in `(str.length() + 7)`.

I'm afraid that your way seems to the the most "neat".  If you can explain why you don't like it maybe we can find a better workaround.

Comment: By neat I mean, not having to add an extra argument that exists only to trick Formattor into printing the number of spaces I want. It looks messy and would confuse anyone who isn't aware of this issue. Maybe a method that returns a string of spaces would be better for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend text into your string.
Another way to reapet any string which you can use this code:-

```
String str = "abc";
String repeated = StringUtils.repeat(str, 3);
```

here StringUtils is org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils class.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#leftPad%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
String line = "Hello World!";
int numberOfSpaces = 2;
String lineWithSpacePadding = StringUtils.leftPad(line, line.length() + numberOfSpaces);
```